# replacing show() with setVisible(boolean)

Tags: java, class, jframe

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;
public class DiceSimulation extends JApplet
{
  /* Initialising Applet */
  public DiceSimulation()
  {
    this.setContentPane(new DiceRollPanel());
  }
  /* method main */
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    /* frame */
    JFrame dicewindow = new JFrame();
    dicewindow.setTitle("Dice Simulation");
    dicewindow.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dicewindow.setContentPane(new DiceRollPanel());
    dicewindow.pack();
    dicewindow.setVisible(boolean);
  }
}
```

**error '.class' expected**
I was told to use show() but since that is deprecated I chose to use setVisible(boolean) instead but keep coming across this error as I continue to make changes. Could someone point out my mistake if possible. Still at the beginner level of using java.

Comment: `setVisible(true);` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to give it a parameter of type `boolean`

boolean is a primitive type and can have a value of either `true` or `false`

You can call `setVisible(true)` to show and `setVisible(false)` to hide

Comment: possibly the most ridiculous mistake I have made so far. Thank you!